# Removing stopwords; can't get rid of certain stopwords no matter what?

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-cleaning, stop-words

I'm trying to clean up a train set of newsarticles (**input** newsarticles)
My **output** here is the 10 most common words in the articles.

When using the nltk stopwords certain words still got through:
**['the','would','said','one','also','like','could','he']**
So I added them to stopwords myself. I tried both the append method and the extend as shown in the code below. But the desired stopwords (words to be emitted) **"the"**, and **"he"** is not removed.

Anyone knows why?
Or know what I might be doing wrong?

```
(And yes; Ive googled it ALOT)
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
import string
import re
from IPython.display import display
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer


#importing dataset and making a copy as string
data = pd.read_csv('train.csv', encoding="ISO-8859-1")

data1 = data.copy()
data1.text = data1.text.astype(str)
to_drop = ['id',
               'title',
               'author',]
data1.drop(to_drop, inplace=True, axis=1)


#cleaning text for punctuation, whitespace, splitting, and set to lower 
data1['text'] = data1['text'].str.strip().str.lower().str.replace('[^\w\s] ', '').str.split()


#removing stopwords
stopwords = nltk.corpus.stopwords.words('english')
custom_words = ['the','would','said','one','also','like','could','he']
stopwords.extend(custom_words)
data1['text'] = data1['text'].apply(lambda x: [item for item in x if item not in stopwords ])
data1['text']= data1['text'].apply(lambda x: " ".join(x))

vectorizer = CountVectorizer(max_features=1500, analyzer='word')
train_voc = vectorizer.fit_transform(data1['text'])
sum_words = train_voc.sum(axis=0)
words_freq = [(word, sum_words[0, idx]) for word, idx in vectorizer.vocabulary_.items()]
words_freq =sorted(words_freq, key = lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)



print (words_freq[:10])



display(data1.head())
```

Output:

```
[('the', 31138), ('people', 28975), ('new', 28495), ('trump', 24752), ('president', 18701), ('he', 17254), ('us', 16969), ('clinton', 16039), ('first', 15520), ('two', 15491)]

    text    label
0   house dem aidewe didnât even see comeyâs l...   1
1   ever get feeling life circles roundabout rathe...   0
2   truth might get fired october 292016 tension i...   1
3   videos 15 civilians killed single us airstrike...   1
4   print iranian woman sentenced six years prison...   1
```

**Someone asked for an example.** 
This is an [example](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/removing-stop-words-nltk-python/)  where you can see 2 outputs; one before removing stopwords, and one after removing them.
The same goes for this data, only that its a much larger dataset, and the output is the most common words aswell.
Example output:

without stopwords: ['This', 'is', 'a', 'sample', 'sentence', ',', 'showing', 
'off', 'the', 'stop', 'words', 'filtration', '.']

With stopwords['This', 'sample', 'sentence', ',', 'showing', 'stop',
'words', 'filtration', '.']

Comment: What is your input and expected output data?

Comment: input is news articles(lots of them) . Output is most common words in the articles. But I want to take away all non-relevant words, stopwords. Goal: bag of words, somewhat more useful than this output.

Comment: Can you be more specific and provide any example of input and output data?

Comment: Ive updated the question to be more specific. Input: newsarticles. Output: 10 most common words in the articles. Minus stopwords

Comment: What is `data1` value in you code?

Comment: #importing dataset and making a copy as string
data = pd.read_csv('train.csv', encoding="ISO-8859-1")

data1 = data.copy()
data1.text = data1.text.astype(str)

Comment: Please add this code to the question and provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: after your last processing line, what does `data1['text']` look like?

Comment: Ive added the import of data to the question. And a basic example. Ive already showed the output in the question though

Comment: Not sure if I follow your question. Text is the text in the news-articles without meta-data. After cleaning the dataset the text is : splitted into single words, sorted from the words most common, to less common. All words are to lower, no punctuation, no whitespace and so on. Stopwords are removed aswell. But not "he" and "the" , thats the weird problem. I don't understand why they still are there.

Comment: @Muriel It would be good for you to add a `print(data1['text'].head(1))` to the start of your script, and one just below the last line you have. Your output is not the last line of code you have, there is obviously more going on and it is making it unclear to give help

Comment: Ive edited the code now

Comment: I can't get your code to run with any valid output without swapping the preprocessing replace with the split - `data1['text'] = data1['text'].str.strip().str.lower().str.replace('[^\w\s] ', '').str.split()`. Does that make any difference to you? What version of pandas are you using?

Comment: Haha, yeah, same here. I just edited it from a single line under...sorry. Im using Jupyter

Comment: But any idea on how to remove the custom stop-words, and why they still get printed when I tried append and extend?

Comment: and I use normal pandas? prob new version. Im using Anaconda to run